# passing variables into functions javascript

Tags: javascript, function, math

I can't quite seem to figure out why the variables I created don't return the way I would like.  Simple math problems here, multiplication and division.  Creating the variable outside of the function returns NaN, but calling within the function returns what I suspect.

Snippets below:

```
var p = parseInt(document.getElementById('watts').value, 10);
var e = parseInt(document.getElementById('volts').value, 10);

function calcAmps(){
  var p = parseInt(document.getElementById('watts').value, 10);
  var e = parseInt(document.getElementById('volts').value, 10);
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = p/e;
};
```

Now, using the variable within the function work fine.  The math executes without issue.  But if I comment out the variables within the function and attempt to use the global variables, I get NaN.

Any thoughts?  Should be a softball question.

Comment: can you try to run this ? 

    var p = 12;
    var e = 5;
    alert(calcAmps());

    function calcAmps(){
      return p/e;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initialized outside the function, the values are only fetched from the DOM **once**, when the script first runs. Inside the function, the values are fetched at the point that the computation actually happens.

To be clear and explicit, the following:

```
var p = parseInt(document.getElementById('watts').value, 10);
```

does **not** mean that a permanent dynamic relationship is established between the variable `p` and the input field. Instead, it instructs the runtime to fetch the *current* value of the field *at the time the code runs*.  After that point, nothing you type in the input field will be reflected as the value of `p`.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  Thanks for the input and knowledge!